# Why does my check for uppercase always result in true even when it shouldn't?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script to check a password if it has upper case or not, but it always shows that it has upper case.

I tried to use

```
if [[ $password =~ [A-Z] ]]; then
echo "Contains Upper Case"
```

but it always prints that.

This is my script:

```
read -p "Enter Password: " password
if [ ${#password} -lt 8 ]; then 
echo "TOO SHORT , MAN! " 
fi
if [[ $password =~ [A-Z] ]]; then
echo "Contains Upper Case"
fi
```

Comment: When I test it, I don't get a message after `aaaaaaaaaaa`. Are you sure you are enterering and testing the same variable?

Comment: Show your shebang and how do you run your script?

Comment: "it always print that." ... what is "that"?

Comment: I would use `if [[ $password == *[[:upper:]]* ]]` myself, that that regex match should work, unless your version of bash is too old, or if you're actually using `/bin/sh` instead of bash.

Comment: Are you using an "exotic" locale? What happens if you use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]`?

Comment: Also, a minimal example would be just `[[ x =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo 'Matches'`; can you try that, and then the same with `[[ x =~ [[:upper:]] ]] && echo 'Matches'` and `LC_ALL=C [[ x =~ [A-Z] ]] && echo 'Matches'`?

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use `[A-Z]`.** It works only in some language settings / locales (the ones where ordering looks  like `ABCD...Zabcd...z`, intead of like `AaBb...Zz`).

For your code to work everywhere, use `[[:upper:]]` instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || { echo "ERROR: Shell is not bash" >&2; exit 1; }

if [[ $password =~ [[:upper:]] ]]; then
  echo "Contains at least one upper-case character"
else
  echo "Does not contain one or more upper-case characters"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much , this Worked For Me .